# VSCode - how to compare current file with that of remote repository version?

Tags: visual-studio-code

coming from IntelliJ, I really miss context menu to compare current file version with that of remote version ?

Is there any plugin or other way to achieve this ?

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens ?

Comment: I have it installed already, but context menu against a file doesn't show any option. can you please post screenshot ?

Comment: If you go to the command palette and type "git compare" a series of command will pop-up, including comparing with other branches, revisions or files. If they don't maybe you didn't load the git repository folder

Comment: Thanks, I got it. In VSCode it's "Open Changes with previous Revision". This sentence is quite confusing compared to IntelliJ's; "Compare with...". MS needs to fix these simple instructions for sure.

Comment: The question does not even say anything about git.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @ChatterOne for the hints.

- Install marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens
- Right clicks on modified filed and choose "Open Changes with.."

[image]